# Automatic filling of identical registration fields at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to help. I have a next form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="email" name="email-repeat">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" name="password-repeat">
    <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

and I want when I reload to page, that browser to autocomplete all fields from saved data in the browser(email and password) twice password and twice email. I tried a few combinations with attribute of autocomplete, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should add autocomplete="off" to the inputs that you don't want to be filled automatically.

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email">
<input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="email-repeat">
<input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password">
<input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password-repeat">
<input type="submit" value="">
```

You can find details in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: Unfortunately autocomplete do not work correctly, browser filling some of them

Comment: For password fileds you can use :

<input type="password" name="pwd" autocomplete="new-password">